# cut part image from uiimageview

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimage, core-graphics

I have a quick question.

I am trying to draw a shape on a picture and be able to cut what is in the circle. Any ideas how I would go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use core graphics for that. Create a mask with `CGImageMaskCreate`, and then use `CGImageCreateWithMask` to combine mask with the image.
Source and example: [How to Mask an Image](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html)

Comment: So essentially if i want to just draw a shape, i can fill up the shape then use the mask?

Comment: @user281300: If you mean you fill the whole area first and then mask to create the shape, yes you can.

Comment: yes that's what i meant cheers. Did no think of using masking before.